# Array returning incorrect index?

Tags: java, audio

I want to make a music-playing program. The problem is that when I use an array to store the songs, something weird happens. In this program, all I am doing is declaring an array of 3 songs. Then, I try print the name of the first song in the array. It turns out, it only ever gives me the name of the last song in the array.

This is the simplest program I could make to demonstrate this issue. I've tried switching up the songs and trying to print different elements, but at this point I'm stumped.

Here is the class that prints the name of the song

```
public class Music {

    //List of songs
    private static Song[] songs =
        {new Song("C:\\Users\\dunca\\workspace\\Example\\songs\\Back In Black.wav"),
            new Song("C:\\Users\\dunca\\workspace\\Example\\songs\\Thunderstruck.wav"),
            new Song("C:\\Users\\dunca\\workspace\\Example\\songs\\TNT.wav")};

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Prints the name of the first element in the array
        System.out.println(songs[0].getName());}
}
```

And here is the song class

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;

public class Song {

    //Initializing variables
    private static String path = "";
    private static File sound = new File(path); 
    public Clip c;

    //Constructor
    public Song(String str) {
        path = str;
        sound = new File(path);}

    //Initializes the AudioStream
    public void init() {

        try {

            AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(sound);
            c = AudioSystem.getClip();
            c.open(ais);}

        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR");}
    }

    //Returns just the name of the song
    public String getName() {

        String str = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1, path.length() - 4);

        return str;}

    //Starts the song
    public void play() {
        c.start();}

    //Stops the song
    public void stop() {
        c.stop();}
}
```

When I type `System.out.println(songs[0].getName());`, I expect the output to be `Back In Black`, but instead I get `TNT`. No matter which element I try to print, the result is always the last element in the array.

`System.out.println(songs[0].getName());`

- Expected Output: "Back In Black"
- Actual Output: "TNT"

`System.out.println(songs[1].getName());`

- Expected Output: "Thunderstruck"
- Actual Output: "TNT"

`System.out.println(songs[2].getName());`

- Expected Output: "TNT"
- Actual Output: "TNT"

I am stumped.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `path` shouldn't be `static`

Comment: Both fields path and file should not be static! The real answer: every character in your code matters! You don't use a keyword like static because you can, but because you understand what it means and when you need it!